# Install rpm on machine without network access

Tags: drivers, rpm

I am debugging my computer which is running Ubuntu. I got a driver for PCIE and I need to install this driver.

So first I need to run this command: `rpmbuild -tb igb.tar.gz`, however I'm getting the following error message:

```
'rpmbuild' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:  
apt-get install rpm
```

However this unit currently does not have a network driver. Where can I get the rpmbuild without using apt-get?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/rpm) on a different computer. The link is at the bottom, either click i386 or amd64 depending on what architecture your PC without the network driver is. This is the Trusty one - you can get the package for a different version using the links after 'Search in specific suite:' at the top.
2. Put the package on a USB stick.
3. Transfer the package from the USB stick onto the computer that doesn't have Internet.
4. Navigate to the directory that the package is in, in a Terminal.
5. Use the command `sudo dpkg -i foo` to install the package (replace `foo` with the exact name of the package - use the command `ls` in the directory to check what the package name is and type it in exactly).

If you need any extra help on any of these steps please comment and I will edit my answer with more information in the relevant section.